How to Handle Custom Keyboard Navigation in WebView with TalkBack Enabled on Android TV?
I'm developing a web application that runs on Android TVs using WebView and implements custom keyboard navigation. The app works as expected with custom navigation handling. However, when TalkBack is enabled, my web application stops receiving key events, making custom navigation impossible.
Is there a way to configure the WebView or handle key events such that my web application can manage navigation even when TalkBack is enabled?
